# Find the impulse response of a causal 52 day moving average system to be used in stock market

Tags: finite-impulse-response, frequency-response, impulse-response, dsp-core, moving-average

Moving average system……………………….
How to solve this one?

Answer (score 2):

The impulse response for a non-weighted average is simply a uniform function over the duration. For a discrete time implementation, this would be all ones for every sample, and then the result would be divided by the total samples (which is the formula for an average!).